# SOAP Procedure "xx" not Present

Tags: php, magento, soap

Google couldn't help me, maybe someone here can help me with this issue :(

I'm trying to connect to my own Magento extension API (soap v2) and getting the Procedure "XX" not Present error, but not on all my connections (I'm connecting to different Stores to the same API but the error occurs only at one store (all Stores have the same codebase)).

When I call the __getFunctions() function, it returns the correct functions.

Here's my SOAP Client Call:

```
try {
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
    $this->connection = new \SoapClient('http://'.$url.'/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1', array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    $this->session = $this->connection->login($username, $password);
} catch(exception $e) {
    return 'No Soap Connection available';
}
```

I already cleared the /tmp directory (`rm -f /tmp/wsdl*`) from all wsdl files, cleared Magento cache several times (disabled cache completely), reinstalled the extension. I even tried to set `soap.wsdl_cache_ttl` to 1 and `soap.wsdl_cache_limit` to 1.

I don't know what I can do anymore.

**EDIT:**

I added '?rev='.time()' to the url, so that every time a new "file" will be loaded. But this didn't helped either.

Comment: Noone ever encountered that problem before?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679288/php-soap-procedure-functionname-not-present

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when tried to use my function in SoapUI. Nothing worked for me until I clicked "Recreates a default request from the schema". So I suppose the problem can be if you dont fill all the params in a function and dosnt have any validaiton