# Remove <return> tag, in submitting data to Soap Server with PHP

Tags: php, soap

**Actual result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
            <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
                <errorMsg xsi:type="xsd:string">Ok</errorMsg>
                <status xsi:type="xsd:string">0</status>
                <timeStamp xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00</timeStamp>
            </return>
        </ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Expected result** without `<return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"></return>` tag.

*I am doing it first time, and actually I know almost nothing about Soap Server, could you tell me, how can I remove return tag ?*

this is the code on server side:

```
class PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse {
    public $errorMsg = "Ok";
    public $status = "0";
    public $timeStamp = "2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00";
}


class MyAPI {
    function PerformTransactionArguments() {
        return new PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse;
    }
}

$options=array('uri'=>'localhost/');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL,$options);
$server->setClass('MyAPI');
$server->handle();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want you must make a WSDL document and pass it both to the server and the client. Let's start creating a WSDL document named `wsdl-pruebas.wsdl` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="TransactionArguments"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/pruebas"
             targetNamespace="http://localhost/pruebas">
    <types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/pruebas">
            <xs:element name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="errorMsg" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="timeStamp" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="PerformTransactionArgumentsRequest"/>
    <message name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
        <part name="return" element="ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="PerformTransactionArgumentsPortType">
        <operation name="PerformTransactionArguments">
            <input message="PerformTransactionArgumentsRequest"/>
            <output message="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="PerformTransactionArgumentsBinding" type="PerformTransactionArgumentsPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="PerformTransactionArguments">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input/>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://localhost/pruebas" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponseService">
        <documentation>Returns an error message.</documentation>
        <port name="PerformTransactionArgumentsPort" binding="PerformTransactionArgumentsBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/pruebas/soap-server.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The definition seems overwhelming, but it's quite simple once you analize it section by section, which we'll analize below. First we define the type for the response here:

```
<types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost/pruebas">
        <xs:element name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="errorMsg" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="timeStamp" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</types>
```

As you can see it's identical to your class. We'll use it later. Next we define the request and response messages:

```
<message name="PerformTransactionArgumentsRequest"/>
<message name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
    <part name="return" element="ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse"/>
</message>
```

We're defining an empty request, but a response of the type of your class. Take note of the `name` attribute, which values `return`. This is what you currently see in the response of the server. Next we define the "interface" for the operations of your SOAP server:

```
<portType name="PerformTransactionArgumentsPortType">
    <operation name="PerformTransactionArguments">
        <input message="PerformTransactionArgumentsRequest"/>
        <output message="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

`input` and `output` simply point to the messages described above. Next we define the "details" of the portType:

```
<binding name="PerformTransactionArgumentsBinding" type="PerformTransactionArgumentsPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="PerformTransactionArguments">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input/>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://localhost/pruebas" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Here **soap:binding** tells us it's using SOAP 1.1.

Finally we expose the binding through the service section:

```
<service name="PerformTransactionArgumentsResponseService">
    <documentation>Returns an error message.</documentation>
    <port name="PerformTransactionArgumentsPort" binding="PerformTransactionArgumentsBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost/pruebas/soap-server.php"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

The **soap:address** point to the URL of your soap server script (in this example, *`http://localhost/pruebas/soap-server.php`*).

After defining the WSDL document, we code the soap server script (in this example will be named `soap-server.php`):

```
class PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse {
    public $errorMsg = "Ok";
    public $status = "0";
    public $timeStamp = "2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00";
}


class MyAPI {
    function PerformTransactionArguments() {
        return new PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse;
    }
}

$options = [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
];

$server = new SoapServer('http://localhost/pruebas/soap-pruebas.wsdl', $options);
$server->setClass('MyAPI');
$server->handle();
```

This time we provide the URL of our WSDL document and modify the `$options` array.

To see all this in action we create a SOAP client script (in this example will be `soap-client.php`):

```
try {
    $options = [
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'trace'=>1
    ];

    $client = new SOAPClient('http://localhost/pruebas/soap-pruebas.wsdl', $options);

    $response = $client->PerformTransactionArguments();

    header('Content-type:text/xml');
    echo $client->__getLastResponse();
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Again, we specify the URL of our WSDL document. Running the client script will give this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/pruebas" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse xsi:type="ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
            <errorMsg xsi:type="xsd:string">Ok</errorMsg>
            <status xsi:type="xsd:string">0</status>
            <timeStamp xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00</timeStamp>
        </ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What differs from the generated response of your soap server script?

In the **soap:binding** definition, if we modify the value of the `style`sttribute to from `document` to `rpc`:

```
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

We'll get this response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/pruebas" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
            <return xsi:type="ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse">
                <errorMsg xsi:type="xsd:string">Ok</errorMsg>
                <status xsi:type="xsd:string">0</status>
                <timeStamp xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00</timeStamp>
            </return>
        </ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which is the response you're getting currently.

**EDIT:**
Lastly, if we change the **soap:body** line:

```
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://localhost/pruebas" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
```

to this:

```
<soap:body use="literal"/>
```

The response will be:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/pruebas">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
            <errorMsg>Ok</errorMsg>
            <status>0</status>
            <timeStamp>2011-04-26T19:13:55.421875+05:00</timeStamp>
        </ns1:PerformTransactionArgumentsResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**NOTE:** For this I'm assuming the scripts and the WDSL are located in `http://localhost/pruebas/`.

Comment: so great, thank you very much, did not expect such answer)) but can you clarify if I should create one .wsdl file : wsdl-pruebas.wsdl  or soap-pruebas.wsdl ? first I thought no matter how to name file, but then I am getting error                                                                                   <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Procedure 'PerformTransactionArguments' not present</faultstring> . I tried solve it myself, but ineffectually. what can be the reason of it ? and I am checking it in Postman extension, does it matter ?

Comment: You can name the wsdl file however you want, just make sure you reference it correctly both in the server and the client. I haven't used Postman, but it should work. Also, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679288/php-soap-procedure-functionname-not-present

Comment: thank you very much) I found the solution, the problem was from client side, they had their own wsdl parameters, finally it worked. Thank you again:)